# "Российский" Volkswagen Tiguan

Tags: выбор-слов

Volkswagen Tiguan российского производства - верно ли будет сказать "российский" Volkswagen Tiguan?

Answer (score 3):

Вполне, за вычетом некоторой неточности (фольксваген, находящийся в России или произведенный в России?). Российский Volkswagen Tiguan. И даже кавычки не нужны.

Comment: Автомобиль, произведенный в России

Comment: Я поняла вас, но без указания контекста поймет не каждый. В остальном - можно.

Comment: Кавычки могут иметь некоторый смысл, если подразумевается, что продукт - не совсем российский или псевдороссийский. Ну вроде как акцент на том, что российская только сборка, а все детали из-за границы привозят. Вариант умозрительный, это только для понимания того, что в принципе могут означать кавычки, использованные автором.